# Webhook for "shop" configuration?

Tags: shopify

I know it is possible to receive the shop's configuration using `GET /admin/shop.json`. But is it also possible to keep this information up to date somehow? I did not see a webhook listed for `shop/update` in the [API docs](http://api.shopify.com/webhook.html).

Comment: You can poll it (within a reasonable interval, to avoid hitting your API call limit needlessly), but presently there is no webhook.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I suppose I will have to make my users update their info manually. If you could post your comment as an answer below, I could accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can poll it (within a reasonable interval, to avoid hitting your API call limit needlessly), but presently there is no webhook.